# clock countdown calculation in python

Tags: python, loops, counter, clock

I want to write a function called `boom(h,m,s)` that after input from main starts printing in **HH:MM:SS** format the countdown clock, and then prints "boom".
I'm not allowed to use existing modules except the time.sleep(), so I have to base on While\For loops.

```
import time

def boom(h,m,s):
    while h>0:
        while m>0:
            while s>0:
                print ("%d:%d:%d"%(h,m,s))
                time.sleep(1)
                s-=1
            print ("%d:%d:%d"%(h,m,s))
            time.sleep(1)
            s=59
            m-=1
        print ("%d:%d:%d"%(h,m,s))
        time.sleep(1)
        s=59
        m=59
        h-=1
    while h==0:
        while m==0:
            while s>0:
                print ("%d:%d:%d"%(h,m,s))
                time.sleep(1)
                s-=1
    print ("BooM!!")
```

I figured how to calculate the seconds part, but when I input zeros on H and M parameters, it's messing with the clock.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
while h==0:
    while m==0:
        while s>0:
```

If `m == 0`, and `s == 0`  the while loop doesn't break, so there is an infinite loop.
Just add an else clause to the (last and) inner-most `while`, like so:

```
while s>0:
    ...
else: # executed once the above condition is False.
    print ('BooM!!')
    return # no need to break out of all the whiles!!
```

Comment: if m==0 and s == 0 wouldnt it not enter the loop at all?

Comment: Let's assume `m==0`, so you enter the while loop, once the condition of `s > 0` is False, the inner while ends, but we are still in the outer while, so then we enter an infinite loop, which occurs after `s > 0` is False. IF `m==0`, you enter the `m` while loop which we don't exit.. :) In-case I am not clear, use the debugger and you shall understand

Comment: ahh duh (camt believe I didnt notice that) :) +1 ... especially since unlike me you didnt just do his homework for him

Answer (score 0):

just convert it all to seconds and convert it back when you print ...

```
def hmsToSecs(h,m,s):
    return h*3600 + m*60 + s

def secsToHms(secs):
    hours = secs//3600
    secs -= hours*3600
    mins = secs//60
    secs -= mins*60
    return hours,mins,secs

def countdown(h,m,s):
    seconds = hmsToSecs(h,m,s)
    while seconds > 0:
         print "%02d:%02d:%02d"%secsToHms(seconds)
         seconds -= 1
         sleep(1)
    print "Done!"
```

Comment: I changed it ... i didnt read it all the way to start with :P

Comment: You aren't printing `"BooM!!"`  :)